# How can i filter a Product by price in DRF

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-redux, django-views

I have a model class Products in which I simple specify product-URL, product-title and product-price as attributes. and make Serializer.py file use ModelSerializer and pass data to Reactjs Now I can't understand that how can i filter products by there price so if I fetch API in react all High price are sorted first or low after according to user need or our option...thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do this:

**1. Using DRF Filter Backends:**

[DRF Filtering Documentation - Ordering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter)

Based on the official DRF documentation, you need to specify your filter backends in your settings or your view like so:

```
from rest_framework import filters

class ProductListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ['price']
```

You're going to be able to filter your list with a request parameter:

```
http://example.com/api/products?ordering=price
```

Or reverse ordering by:

```
http://example.com/api/products?ordering=-price
```

**2. hardcoding the sorting in your queryset**

```
class ProductListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-score')
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

Basically, you don't want to hardcode your ordering unless you are always sure you want the results to be ordered that way. Otherwise, filter backends are the way to go.

Comment: No problem bro, glad I could help. Also, check out the guideline for commenting and answers [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)